# Sqoop job through oozie

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

I have created a sqoop job called TeamMemsImportJob which basically pulls data from sql server into hive.
I can execute the sqoop job through the unix command line by running the following command:

```
sqoop job –exec TeamMemsImportJob
```

If I create an oozie job with the actual scoop import command in it, it runs through fine.
However if I create the oozie job and run the sqoop job through it, I get the following error:

```
oozie job -config TeamMemsImportJob.properties -run

>>> Invoking Sqoop command line now >>>

4273 [main] WARN org.apache.sqoop.tool.SqoopTool – $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
4329 [main] INFO org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop – Running Sqoop version: 1.4.4.2.1.1.0-385
5172 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage – Cannot restore job: TeamMemsImportJob
5172 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage – (No such job)
5172 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool – I/O error performing job operation: java.io.IOException: Cannot restore missing job TeamMemsImportJob
at org.apache.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage.read(HsqldbJobStorage.java:256)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.execJob(JobTool.java:198)
```

it looks as if it cannot find the job. However I can see the job as below

```
[root@sandbox ~]# sqoop job –list
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
14/06/25 08:12:08 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.4.2.1.1.0-385
Available jobs:
TeamMemsImportJob
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Hi @Colman, Is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `--meta-connect` flag while creating a job to create a custom Sqoop metastore database so that Oozie can have access.

```
sqoop \
job \
--meta-connect \
"jdbc:hsqldb:file:/on/server/not/hdfs/sqoop-metastore/sqoop-meta.db;shutdown=true" \
--create \
jobName \
-- \
import \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:port:sid \
--username username \
--password-file /path/on/hdfs/server.password \
--table TABLE \
--incremental append \
--check-column ID \
--last-value "0" \
--target-dir /path/on/hdfs/TABLE
```

When you need to execute jobs, you can do it from Oozie the regular way, but make sure to include `--meta-connect` to indicate where the job is stored.

Answer (score 0):

If we see the log we can see that it cannot find the stored job.

Since you are using the native hsql db.

To make Sqoop jobs available across other systems you should configure other database for example mysql which can be accessed by all systems.

From documentation

> Running sqoop-metastore launches a shared HSQLDB database instance on
>   the current machine. Clients can connect to this metastore and create
>   jobs which can be shared between users for execution
>
> The location of the metastore’s files on disk is controlled by the
>   sqoop.metastore.server.location property in conf/sqoop-site.xml. This
>   should point to a directory on the local filesystem.
>
> The metastore is available over TCP/IP. The port is controlled by the
>   sqoop.metastore.server.port configuration parameter, and defaults to
>   16000.
>
> Clients should connect to the metastore by specifying
>   sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.url or --meta-connect with the
>   value jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://:/sqoop. For example,
>   jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://metaserver.example.com:16000/sqoop.
>
> This metastore may be hosted on a machine within the Hadoop cluster,
>   or elsewhere on the network.

Can you check if that db is accessible from other systems.